# How can I empty a request on Laravel Controller?

Tags: controller, request, laravel-5.6

```
   public function product(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->['name'];
        $price = $request->['price'];
  /*I want to clear the $request first as I want to send the request to other function*/

        $request->merge(['city' => $city,'id' => $id]);

     ...
    }
```

How can I clear the $request contents.

I tried

```
$request->only(['']);
```

it's no use!

Comment: What do you wan't to clear? Remove name and price from request?

Comment: yes! I want to make  a clean request

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request)
{
        dump('Pass Blank Array');
        dump($request->only([]));
        dd($request->all());
}
```

### [image]

### **OR**

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request)
{
    dump('Before Flash');
    dump($request);
    $request = $request->flash();
    dump('After Flash');
    dd($request);
}
```

[image]

- After `flash()` you can not access `$request->all()` or any other things from `$request` variable.
- If you want to use `only()` than you need to pass blank array like `$request->only([])`. By using this empty array you get empty array of `$request` variable.

***NOTE***

1. `$request->flash()` reset all details of variable.
2. `$request->only([])` return only selected values pass in array.

---

I hope this will help you!